# adjust column spaces in mathematical modelling

Tags: spacing, equations

I am using the overleaf to formulate my mathematical formulation. But the problem is that my formulation is wide and I intend to decrease the space between two columns. I am wondering how can do it? Any help will be appreciated in advance. Here is a sample of my mathematical formulation.

Thanks,
Ali

[image]

```
\begin{equation}    
\begin{array}{rrcrcrcrcrcrcrcrll   
\tiny    
\label{eq:ex1-updated_BMASTER_2}    
  \min & \theta_{1}^{+} &-& \theta_{1}^{-} && && &+& 2y_1 && &-& 4 y_3 &&  \\
  \min & && && \theta_{2}^{+} &-& \theta_{2}^- &+& 4y_1 &-& 6y_2 &-& 3y_3 &&  \\
  & && && && &-& y_{1} &+& 6y_{2} &+&4y_{3} &\leqq& 2,\\
  & && && && && && 3y_{2} &+& 5y_{3} &\leqq& 2\\
  & -\theta_{1}^{+} &+& \theta_{1}^{-} && && &+& 0.67 y^{1} &+& 0.5 y^{2} &+& y_{3} &\leqq& 0.83\\ 
  & && && -\theta^{+}_{2} &+& \theta^{-}_{2} &+& 1.3 y_{1} &+& 1.8 y_{1} &+& 3.33 y_{3} &\leqq& 2.2,\\ 
  & -0.23\theta_{1}^{+} &+& 0.23 \theta_{1}^{-} &-& 0.76\theta_{2}^{+} &+& 0.76 \theta_{2}^{-} &+& 1.18 y_{1} &+& 0.88 y_{2} &+& 1.76 y_{3} &\leqq& 1.47\\
  &\theta_{1}^{+}&,&\theta_{1}^{-}&,&\theta_{2}^{+}&,&\theta_{2}^{-}&,&y_{1}&,&y_{2}&,&y_{3} &\geqq& 0.
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `\tiny` is a text-mode command and thus mustn't be use in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you place only the 5 inequalities in the heart of the `array`. The readability of the `\min` statements and of the final line with the 7 non-negativity constraints does not benefit -- and, arguably, suffers -- from placing them in the main body of the `array`.

Observe that with this setup, it's not necessary to reduce the font size in order to fit the equation inside the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amssymb}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for columns with math-bin and math-rel objects
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{15}{l}{#1}} % handy short-cut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ex1-updated_BMASTER_2}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{array}{ *{7}{rC} l }
\mc{\min\quad \theta_{1}^{+} - \theta_{1}^{-} + 2y_1 - 4 y_3}  \\
\mc{\min\quad \theta_{2}^{+} - \theta_{2}^- + 4y_1 - 6y_2 - 3y_3}   \\
\mc{$such that$}\\
 && && && && -y_{1} &+& 6y_{2} &+& 4y_{3} &\leqq& 2\\
 && && && && &&         3y_{2} &+& 5y_{3} &\leqq& 2\\
 -\theta_{1}^{+} &+& \theta_{1}^{-} && && &+& 0.67 y^{1} &+& 0.5 y^{2} &+& y_{3} &\leqq& 0.83\\ 
 && && -\theta^{+}_{2} &+& \theta^{-}_{2} &+& 1.3 y_{1} &+& 1.8 y_{1} &+& 3.33 y_{3} &\leqq& 2.2\\ 
 -0.23\theta_{1}^{+} &+& 0.23 \theta_{1}^{-} &-& 0.76\theta_{2}^{+} &+& 0.76 \theta_{2}^{-} &+& 1.18 y_{1} &+& 0.88 y_{2} &+& 1.76 y_{3} &\leqq& 1.47\\[1ex]
\mc{$and $ \theta_{1}^{+},\theta_{1}^{-},\theta_{2}^{+},\theta_{2}^{-},y_{1},y_{2},y_{3} \geqq 0.}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```